# Why are some things attracted to you but others repelled by you in rotating reference frames?

Tags: angular-momentum, machs-principle, thought-experiment

Note that my understanding of general-relativity is rudimentary. If I understand right, it means that basically any reference frame can be considered stationary, but there may be random gravitational forces going in any which way.

A though experiment. It is the year 2100, and to celebrate, they are going to shoot an astronaut into SPACE. And by an astronaut, they mean you. Also the cannon is shaped like a shotgun (for whatever reason), and will even spin you. They fire you, and the acceleration causes you to go unconscious.

You wake up.  The earth and any massive objects are far away. Also, everything is spinning. You at first think that this is because of motion sickness, but you then realize that everything is actually spinning around you. It is great feeling to think everything revolves around you.  You then realize that everything is just going around a line that goes through you. Still cool. You conclude that there must be a force throughout the entire universe that pushes everything to this line. You decide to pull out a camera to take a selfie to show your friends when you get home.

You accidentally let go, and the camera stars spiraling away from you. (Also note the cameras weight is negligible, so you do not question why this isn't an equal opposite force, and from earth's perspective, you won't loss any angular momentum.) This is odd, because the camera was still, but then something caused it to spiral away from you, where as everything else seems attracted to you (or that line.)

**So in summary**, if from the earth a rotating object releases a projectile (which isn't massive enough to affect the angular momentum in a noticeable way.) Why from the objects reference frame would the object fly away while everything else just orbits a line through it? Or do I just grossly misunderstand gr.

Update: I want to understand what forces are present according to the astronaut's reference frame. Are the forces going towards the line, away, or something else. I do realize it is related to Mach's Principle. On later thought, this is basically trying to figure out exactly how Mach's Principle is applied. Stars out there affect us down here, but how?

Comment: Hi PyRulez, can you cut down some of the extraneous content to just the physics question?  Also, this sure sounds like homework.

Comment: Also, have you read about [Mach's Principle?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle)

Comment: Yes, and I had a sense that it was related to it.

Comment: @BrandonEnright No, not homework. I don't even have a general relativity class (I wish I did though.)

Comment: I don't think your question has much to do with GR.  The answer comes from classical relativity.  A rotating reference frame will see "fictitious forces", namely the Coriolis Force (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force) and the Centrifugal Force (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force_(fictitious)).

Comment: My problem is that certain objects have an inner-ward going force, and others have and outer-ward going force.

Comment: The direction and magnitude of the Coriolis force on an object depends on the angular velocity of the rotating frame and the velocity (relative to the rotating frame) of the object.  The direction and magnitude of the Centrifugal force on an object depends on the angular velocity of the rotating frame and the position (relative to the rotating frame) of the object.

Comment: What was the initial impulse that caused the phone to fly out of the astronaut's hand? I have the impression that in GR, there is field of vectors describing forces at each point, is this correct?

Comment: Your impression is incorrect.  GR describes the gravitational force only.  It does not describe all other forces.  The "impulse" occurs because when you release the phone from your hands then it is no longer a part of your rotating reference frame.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force

Comment: Nothing has an inward going force. Everything has an outward going force.  Where do you think you see an inward going force?